# Trying to figure out how I can align all text sent by my chatbot

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the moment if the chatbot sends a reply which is more than one line, the text isn't fully aligned. Are there any simple fixes for this? Thankyou

```
.botText{
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-align: left;
line-height:25px;
color: rgb(109,111,109);
```

}

```
 <script>
    
function getUserResponse(){
var userText = $('#textInput').val();  

if(userText.trim().length == 0){
    return
}else{
    var userHTML = "<div > <p class='userText'><span>"+userText+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> <img src= {% static 'images/userIcon.png' %} width=50px height=50px style='vertical-align: middle;' >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p></div>";
    
    
$('#textInput').val("");

$('#chatbot').append(userHTML);

$.get('/chatbotModel/getResponse',{userMessage:userText}).done(function(data){
    var returnedMessage = "<p class='botText'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src= {% static 'images/chatbot.png' %} width=50px height=50px  style='vertical-align: middle;' >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span>"+data+"</span/></p>";
    $('#chatbot').append(returnedMessage)

})

}
```

[Image of text output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMGnp.png)

EDIT: HTML code:

```
<div>
   
    <div id="chatbot">
        <p class="botText"><span></span></p>
      
    </div>
    <div id="userInput">
    <input type="text" class="no_outline" id="textInput" name="userMessage" placeholder="Type your message..."/>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="buttonInput">Send</a>
   
    </div>
</div>
```

chatbot CSS code

```
#chatbot{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

margin-top: 70px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: -1px 4px #d4d4d4;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
```

}

Comment: How do you want it to be aligne? any expected image?

Comment: Could you please provide the current html and css of the chatbox so that we can reproduce your example?

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/q3vo19yu/

Comment: I've made some edits and added the chatbot css code and the HTML code for the main body

Comment: @ChrisG dude your code worked perfectly! thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

You have

```
<p>
   <img>
   <span>...</span>
</p>
```

But you probably want something more like

```
<div>
   <div><img></div>
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Where the outer div is set up to put the contents alongside each other. See the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

An old-fashioned table would work too.

Comment: [Please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: Really? That page is much less relevant to this example. It shows how to flow text in a paragraph into columns, which it not what is wanted here.

Comment: This one is probably better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Column_layouts